# How to get status details for Time Synchronization on Windows?

Tags: windows, time

I need to provide details on the status of the Time Synchronization to external consumers.

On Windows I found the app `w32tm` allowing query the current state as well as configuring. So far I did not find any API neither for C(++) nor C#.

Do you know an API providing details like last synchronization time, current offset to the reference, IP address of the last used peer?

If there is no API available I need to analyze the output of the app `w32tm`. But this is localized. I need a solution which work stable on all customer systems. I tried forcing the output to English with `set LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` and `chcp 437`, both without effect.